# Python regex replace string with pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Regex is `r'[A-z\d,\-.\ \/\n]{1,}'`, This regex will allow alphanumeric + some special chars.

I want to replace characters which are not allowed.

I have tried,

```
re.sub(r'[A-z\d,\-.\ \/\n]{1,}', ' ', 'ASGHB 3 JHDSD eyg && ^&*hdbcd v%^&*B#$%^')
```

Gives output as,

```
' && &* % &* #$% '
```

I want original string as output with replaced special chars (which are not allowed) with white spaces.

Expected output : `ASGHB 3 JHDSD eyg    ^  hdbcd v ^  B   ^`
How to achieve this ?

Comment: `re.sub(r'[^A-z\d,\-.\ \/\n]{1,}', ' ', 'ASGHB 3 JHDSD eyg && ^&*hdbcd v%^&*B#$%^')` => `'ASGHB 3 JHDSD eyg   ^ hdbcd v ^ B ^'` ? You should give your expected result.

Comment: also don't use `[A-z]` until or otherwise you know what it actually does.

Comment: @Silencer Thanks.

Comment: @AvinashRaj should I use it separately ? I though [A-Za-z] and [A-z] are same, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you should use that separately. Both are not same. see what are the other chars that falls within A-z range http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can find all about re.sub [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

So about your question. You should use ^ before your set:

```
If the first character of the set is '^', all the characters that are not in the set will be matched. 
For example, [^5] will match any character except '5', and [^^] will match any character except '^'. 
^ has no special meaning if it’s not the first character in the set.
```